# Separate VueJS children routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-router

> Here is my **router.js** code:

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView,
      meta: {
        title: app.NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.LOGIN_PAGE
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      component: DashboardView,
      redirect: '/dashboard',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: Dashboard,
          name: 'Dashboard',
          meta: { title: app.SMALL_NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.DASHBOARD_PAGE }
        },

        // PRODUCTS START
        // INDEX
        // SHOW
        {
          path: 'product/details/:product_id',
          component: ProductDetails,
          name: 'ProductDetails',
          meta: { title: app.SMALL_NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.PRODUCTS_SHOW_PAGE}
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

> What I am trying to do:

This code runs good but I am trying here to find the best practice and separate my children routes.

I want to separate the **SHOW** route and "INDEX" route in a separated file..

> What I have tried to do:

I have created a **products_routes.js** and I have added this code to it.

```
    let products_routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: Products,
    name: 'Products',
    meta: { title: app.SMALL_NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.PRODUCTS_PAGE }
  }
];

export default products_routes;
```

And I have included this file in my main **router.js** file..

How I inject that code in my **router.js** file after importing it?

I have tried to do this:

```
import products_routes from '@/routes/products_routes';
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView,
      meta: {
        title: app.NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.LOGIN_PAGE
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      component: DashboardView,
      redirect: '/dashboard',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: Dashboard,
          name: 'Dashboard',
          meta: { title: app.SMALL_NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.DASHBOARD_PAGE }
        },

        // PRODUCTS START
        // INDEX
        products_routes[0], // HERE I INJECTED MY products routes
        // SHOW
        {
          path: 'product/details/:product_id',
          component: ProductDetails,
          name: 'ProductDetails',
          meta: { title: app.SMALL_NAME + ' | ' + pages_title.PRODUCTS_SHOW_PAGE}
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: try to use es6 desctructoring, will be something like: 
`products_routes[0],` will be`...products_routes[0],`

Comment: @kalidou.diagne that is a very good solution and it solved my problem.. But is there a better way for me to reach what I want or that is a good idea? Also you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dill you can use the same method, and idea is to create different "bundles" separated by categories/groups and do something like modules in vuex:

```
import authRoutes from '@/routes/bundles/authRoutes';
import dashboardRoutes from '@/routes/bundles/dashboardRoutes';
import productRoutes from '@/routes/bundles/productRoutes';

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
   ...authRoutes,
   ...dashboardRoutes,
   ...productRoutes,
  ]
});
```